# Query auto generated table in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities.
One being Courses and other one Batch

```
    @Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Course {
    @Id
    private String uuid;

    @Column
    private String tileImage;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String durationWeek;

    @Column
    private String durationHour;

    @Column
    private int price;

    @Column
    private String apply;

    @Column
    private Integer linkClicked;

    @Column
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Batch> batches;

}
```

And one is Batch

```
    @Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Batch {
    @Id
    private String uuid;

    @Column
    private Date startDate;

    @Column
    private Date endDate;

    @Column
    private String taughtBy;
}
```

On running in Spring boot, it generates 3 table
Course
Batch
Courses_batches (coueseUUid and BatchUUid)

Issue is I want to query the Courses_Batches table? How can I do that by Spring JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data provides many ways to define a query that we can execute. One of these is the `@Query` annotation.

You can use also native SQL to define our query. All we have to do is set the value of the `nativeQuery` attribute to true and define the **native SQL query in the value attribute of the annotation:**

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Courses_Batches cb WHERE cb.course_uuid = ?1", 
            nativeQuery = true)
Object[] findAllByCourseIdInJoinTable(String courseId);
```

You set the column names according to your structure.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the result you want: you probably don't want the tuple `Course_Batches` which represents the association between `Course` and `Batch`, you probably want all `Course` that matches `Batches` or the reverse.

This association does not have any specify attribute, and if were to have attributes, there should be an intermediate entity.

You could use a Spring Data `@Query`, the findBy variant or a `Criteria`: here I assumed that you can use Java multiline string for clarity, but you would have to use concatenation and space for older version of Java:

```
@Query("""
  select new com.example.foobar.PairCourseBatch(c, b)
  from Course c
  left join c.batches b
  where c.uuid = :courseUuid
    and b.uuid = :batchUuid
""")
List<PairCourseBatch> findAllByCourseIdInJoinTable(
  @Param("courseUuid") String courseUuid,
  @Param("batchUuid") String batchUuid
);
```

The `PairCourseBatch` should be a fully qualified type in the query because otherwise JPA would not be able to find it. It expect a constructor taking the `course` and `batch` as parameter.

I don't know if you can use generics (eg: `Pair<Course, Batch>`) but you could return specific attribute and construct a non entity type:

```
select new com.example.foobar.PairCourseBatch(c.tileImage, b.startDate, b.endDate)
```

The advantage of using it is cleared in the return type: you don't have to cast component of an `Object[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but actually i used a native query it worked directly.

Comment: The problem with native query is that you are (in my opinion) missing the point of JPA. What happens if you rename the table?